# Reorder dl/dt/dd and ul/ol/li elements using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a list of translations formatted in HTML. At the moment, provisionally, it's something like

```
<div class="translations">
    <dl>
        <dd lang="en">house</dd>
        <dd lang="fr">maison</dd>
        <dd lang="de">Haus</dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
        <dd lang="en">dog</dd>
        <dd lang="fr">chien</dd>
        <dd lang="de">Hund</dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

Now, I can nominate one language as being primary and style it separately with CSS, viz:

```
.translations dl dd[lang="fr"] {
    color: blue;
}
```

As well as decorating the primary translation, I want to move it to the top of the list within its `dl` e.g. the above should render as if it had been written

```
<dl>
    <dd lang="fr">maison</dd>
    <dd lang="en">house</dd>
    <dd lang="de">Haus</dd>
</dl>
```

but purely using a CSS change (no scripting).

Is this possible?

Comment: Unfortunately `y-index` isn't a real CSS property.

Comment: @Marcel: `top` and `bottom` serve as "y-index", but they don't help here. spraff, If you have variable line heights and wrapping, there's no reliable way to do this, the answers you have are the closest you can get. I wonder why you're trying to do this in CSS and avoiding javascript?

Comment: @Madmartigan: I was thinking more flexible like how `z-index` works, hence the similar name and all.

Comment: @Madmartigan because it needs to be rendered not in a web browser but something else which has no javascript engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The trick is to add some dead space at the top of each `<dl>` using padding. Then, absolutely position your chosen item to the top.

Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2Wy8m/

The CSS you'll need:

```css
.translations dl {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.translations dl dd[lang="fr"] {
    color:blue;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
```

Comment: Bit of a hack but I guess it would do. Is there any way I can express 20px as something other than a magic number?

Comment: Anything fancier would be much more easily-done with jQuery. Pull the correct item out and `prepend()` it to the `<dl>`.

Comment: @spraff 20px would be the `line-height` of your `dd`

Comment: ...and if the line-height is determined by percentages?

Answer (score 0):

If you know for certain, that none of the `<dd>`s will wrap, then you could do something like this:

```css
dl {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 20px; /* or whatever your line-height is */
}

dd[lang="fr"] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fazhc/) for a live example.

Comment: Actually, some of the `dd`s will wrap (they're phrases)

Comment: @spraff Then there is no way to do this without JavaScript

Comment: Like @yunzen said, you'll be out of luck then with CSS alone. (I'm waiting for years for `float: top` to come to browsers.)